# Polymer optimization with window.Polymer = {dom: 'shadow'}

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

For polymer performance optimization, I am trying to use `window.Polymer = window.Polymer || {dom: 'shadow'};`.

In chrome, when I use it I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL polymer.html:2` which is `@license`:

`<!--
@license
Copyright (c) 2015 The Polymer Project Authors`

Here is the script that I am using to load it:

```
var webComponentsSupported = ('registerElement' in document
    && 'import' in document.createElement('link')
    && 'content' in document.createElement('template'));


function createScript(file) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.async = true;
  script.src = file;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}

function createLink(file) {
  var link = document.createElement('link');
  link.async = true;
  link.href = file;
  link.rel = 'import';
  document.head.appendChild(link);
}


if (!webComponentsSupported) {
  //not chrome
  createScript('../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html');
  createScript('../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js');
  createLink('../css/non-chrome-shadow.html');
} else {
  //chrome
  window.Polymer = window.Polymer || {dom: 'shadow'};
  createScript('../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html');
  createLink('../css/chrome-shadow.html');
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing it wrong. Also, since it is in the if condition of the chrome block, couldn't I do `window.Polymer = {dom: 'shadow'};` instead since it's chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Basically this

```
createScript('../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html');
```

You are importing an HTML file instead of a script file. A more proper way would be like this:

```
createLink('../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html');
```

P.S.: You should also check if shadow DOM is available.

Comment: my bad....thanks for pointing the link issue out. Still having the issue in chrome with '
} else {
  window.Polymer = {dom: 'shadow'};
  createLink('../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html');'.

Comment: No need to check if shadow dom is available. Polymer will only honor the request if it is.